# Problem with oh-my-zsh arrows colors in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to modify a ZSH theme but there's something wrong with colors

I can see everything ok in windows terminal:

[image]

I also can see everything ok when I connect to my WSL with the vscode remote tool:

[image]

But when i'm in a local context this happens:

[image]

This is the relevant part of my vscode config:

```
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "DejaVuSansMono Nerd Font",
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe",
"files.exclude": {
    "**/.git": false
 },
"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/usr/bin/zsh",
"gitlens.views.repositories.branches.layout": "list",
"window.zoomLevel": 0,
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
"terminalCursor.background":"#C5C8C6",
"terminalCursor.foreground":"#C5C8C6",
// "terminal.ansiBlack":"#1D1F21",
"terminal.ansiBlue":"#27aecf",
"terminal.ansiBrightBlack":"#969896",
// "terminal.ansiBrightBlue":"#81A2BE",
// "terminal.ansiBrightCyan":"#8ABEB7",
// "terminal.ansiBrightGreen":"#B5BD68",
// "terminal.ansiBrightMagenta":"#B294BB",
// "terminal.ansiBrightRed":"#CC6666",
// "terminal.ansiBrightWhite":"#FFFFFF",
// "terminal.ansiBrightYellow":"#F0C674",
// "terminal.ansiCyan":"#8ABEB7",
"terminal.ansiGreen":"#438b43",
// "terminal.ansiMagenta":"#B294BB",
// "terminal.ansiRed":"#CC6666",
"terminal.ansiWhite":"#ffffff",
"terminal.ansiYellow":"#9e983c"

},
"materialTheme.accent": "Cyan",
"terminal.external.linuxExec": "zsh",
"python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true
  }
```

I'd love to fix the color of those triangles.
I've tried almost everything in my hand but now I have no clue of what to do...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "local context"?

Comment: When I open a project in local instead of remote.

Answer (score 0):

Okey I fixed it,

My problem was that in I needed to add a color for foreground in the vscode setting

```
"terminal.foreground":"#ffffff"
```

apparently the default color for this is some kind of grey and that's what it draw when you don't specify any color.